# Clear all cookies using firefox webextension api

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to create a firefox addon which allows to clear all set cookies. Now I can only get and remove only cookies set for opened tab. How to get all cookies and remove them using firefox webextension api. thanks for helping.

```
browser.tabs.query({}).then(tabs => {
    for (tab of tabs) {
        browser.cookies.getAll({url: tab.url}).then(cookies => {
            for (cookie of cookies) {
                browser.cookies.remove({
                    name: cookie.id
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 3):

`browser.browsingData.removeCookies({});`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browsingData/removeCookies

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to enumerate tabs, just get pass an empty object as `details` argument to `getAll`